# The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\octo\7.4.1\x64\octo.cmd' > failed with exit code 4294967289 Failed to deploy release The process

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-devops, devops, octopus-deploy

I am trying to deploy the AspNet Core 3.1 API build using Azure DevOps, but getting the below error. It was working as expected before. I am able to run the API using the Visual Studio 2019, It is working as expected.

**Error:**

> The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\octo\7.4.1\x64\octo.cmd'
> failed with exit code 4294967289  Failed to deploy release The process
> 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\octo\7.4.1\x64\octo.cmd' failed with exit
> code 4294967289

It's failing in the **Create Octopus Release** build step.

When I fired the build first time it gave me the below error in octopus

**Octopus logs:**

> 2020-07-18T05:38:03.4661299Z Info    IIS configuration complete
> {Message:l} 2020-07-18T05:38:03.4661903Z One or more tasks did not
> complete before the timeout was reached. We waited 00:10:03  for the
> tasks to complete. 2020-07-18T05:38:03.4689131Z One or more tasks did
> not complete before the timeout was reached. We waited 00:10:03  for
> the tasks to complete. 2020-07-18T05:38:03.4691116Z This error is most
> likely occurring while executing octo as part of an automated build
> process. The following doc is recommended to get some tips on how to
> troubleshoot this: https://g.octopushq.com/OctoexeTroubleshooting
> 2020-07-18T05:38:03.4691849Z Exit code: -1
> 2020-07-18T05:38:03.4937068Z ##[error]Error: The process
> 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\octo\7.4.1\x64\octo.cmd' failed with exit
> code 4294967295 2020-07-18T05:38:03.4940746Z ##[error]Failed to deploy
> release The process
> 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\octo\7.4.1\x64\octo.cmd' failed with exit
> code 4294967295 2020-07-18T05:38:03.5051422Z ##[section]Finishing:
> Create Octopus Release: MyApi

Then I again fired the build, and its giving the below error

**Octopus logs:**

> Creating release... There was a problem with your request.
>
> - Release '1.0.0.14' already exists for this project. Please use a different version, or look at using a mask to auto-increment the
>   number.
>
> Error from Octopus Server (HTTP 400 BadRequest) Exit code: -7
> ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\octo\7.4.1\x64\octo.cmd' failed with exit
> code 4294967289
> ##[error]Failed to deploy release The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\octo\7.4.1\x64\octo.cmd' failed with exit
> code 4294967289 Finishing: Create Octopus Release: MyApi

How to solve the error? I have no idea of Azure DevOps and Octopus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by incrementing the build version in the Azure DevOps pipeline.